# Get City/State from Latitude/Longitude via jquery/ajax with google maps geocode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've seen a few jscript/jquery implementations of this concept in reverse, where you can enter a zip code and get a long/lat from the google maps api.

However, in my case, I already have a set of coordinates and was wondering if its possible to dynamically get a textual City, State result from the API when we feed it the long/latitude via jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a process called [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), and Google have quite extensive documentation on it.

An example would be:

```
$.ajax({ url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true',
         success: function(data){
             alert(data.results[0].formatted_address);
             /*or you could iterate the components for only the city and state*/
         }
});
```

Comment: How I can get only the country from the data ?

Comment: Dude I got the answer
for (var i = 0; i < data.results[4].address_components.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < data.results[4].address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
                        if(data.results[4].address_components[i].types[j] == 'country') {
                            var country_code = data.results[4].address_components[i].short_name;
                            alert(country_code);
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: try passing &result_type=locality in request url you'll get city,state,country